# What is the chance of being discovered by zombies as a scout?

Tags: die2nite

If playing a Scout in Die2Nite, how likely is it to be discovered by zombies and therefore being unable to leave the square?

Does the chance depend on the number of zombies? And are there any other factors determining it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been playing the Scout since Hero status opened up and I've never been discovered by zombies automatically. There's quite a bit of text in die2nite that suggests something *might* happen (such as getting an infection from the well if someone "falls in" as reported by the gazette) when, in fact, no functionality exists behind it. I suspect this is the case with Scouts traveling through zombie-controlled territory.

However, do be careful what actions you take while hidden. Unless the action is marked with a scout icon, you will be revealed to the zombies and then you have to be in control of the zone and take an action (0AP required) to regain your hidden status.

**Update:** I have actually heard from people that you can be discovered upon entering a zone. It is apparently very rare and people also report getting xml errors from the game at the same time. Bug? Or untested rare event?

Comment: the xml error that occurs when losing camo is the same one that used to happen when one tried to build with multiple ap's at once. so i believe that that xml error was supposed to be the message warning us that we lost our camo.
that happened to me yesterday and i had to ask for help :/